# How to find which background tasks take most of my memory and CPU time?

Tags: logs, monitoring

While I probably need some kind of monitoring tool like mon or sysstat or something. I am looking for a way to know which tasks take the most of my memory,CPU time etc.

While I understand that each workstation/desktop PC is unique, a typical workload on one of my desktops is something like this :

- Single user (even though the choice is there to have multiple users)
- games - Aisleriot, kshisen
- torrent client - qbittorrent
- mail client - thunderbird
- messaging clients - empathy, telegram and quasselcore and client.
- Browser - Firefox and sometimes tor
- desktop - MATE
- media player - mpv most of the time

it's usually a light workload most of the time but I still see the hdd sensor lighting up which means some background tasks is going intently even though no foreground tasks are happening. While I could use top to find what tasks take most of the CPU and memory cycles, it is only for the moment. I realize I need something which I could figure out over period of time (say a day), runs in the background and produces nice enough graphs to analyze, and most of all has the raw data in user-defined location, say in /home/shirish/mon or whatever directory name is there. It is ok if it is /var/log//logs is where it keeps.

I just need to know few things :

- Which processes take memory and CPU over time, foreground and background.
- Which background processes take most of the CPU and memory
- The logging is tunable, taking snaps every 2-5 minutes.

I am sure there are tools and ways in which people have done it for servers etc. but has anybody done for the above scenario ? If yes, how they went about it ?

Answer (score 0):

As an example, you could use cron to run the following command every *X* minutes:

```
ps --no-headers -eo "uname fname %cpu %mem" | sed -e 's/ \+/,/g' | sed "s/^/$(date --iso-8601='minutes'),/g" >> /path/to/ps.csv
```

Adjusting the `ps` fields as needed.

Then you can use the output file to graph usage using spreadsheet software, gnuplot, or something similar.

**How to add to crontab**

1. Create a script to place the above command in (e.g., `$HOME/bin/pscsv.sh`).
2. chmod +x */path/to/pscsv.sh*
3. `crontab -e` and add a line similar to `*/5 * * * * /path/to/pscsv.sh` adjusting the periodicity to your preference (this example will run every 5 minutes).

Comment: could you elaborate a bit how to a. add it in cron b. what the different sed flags have you shared. The command is cryptic to understand, please elaborate.

Comment: @shirish `crontab -e` Refer [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto#Crontab_Lines) for info on the syntax. The first sed replaces any spaces with commas (to get a CSV format). The second sed prepends each line with the date and time (and comma, see edit).

Comment: I get a bad minute error while trying the above - ps --no-headers -eo "uname fname %cpu %mem" | sed -e 's/ \+/,/g' | sed "s/^/$(date --iso-8601='minutes'),/g" >> /home/shirish/ps.csv
# from https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/308269/how-to-find-which-background-tasks-take-most-of-my-memory-and-cpu-time/308285

Comment: the error it shows is "/tmp/crontab.lKLK8b/crontab":22: bad minute
errors in crontab file, can't install.

Comment: @shirish Can you post the exact line you added in crontab?

Comment: `- ps --no-headers -eo "uname fname %cpu %mem" | sed -e 's/ \+/,/g' | sed "s/^/$(date --iso-8601='minutes'),/g" >> /home/shirish/ps.csv` and a comment in the next line with #

Comment: @shirish Please see my updated answer under *How to add to crontab*

Answer (score 0):

```
//List Processes
ps -la

//Display All Network Activity
nettop
```

A cron task will be your most direct method.
Redirect output to your desired env/path with pipes